# C# Bitmap Image - Exception : Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, image, exception, bitmap, memorystream

I try to work with `Image`. It worked well but sometimes I got “Parameter is not valid” exception. I don't know why that problem occurs, please help me:

```
byte[] img = (byte[])PatientData.Rows[index - 1]["Anh"];
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
imgBox.Image.Dispose();
imgBox.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
using (Bitmap abc = new Bitmap(imgBox.Image)) //Parameter is not valid (Sometimes)
{
    using (Image<Gray, byte> xyz = new Image<Gray, byte>(abc))
    {
        if(Global.xrayPic != null)
        {
            Global.xrayPic.Dispose();
            Global.xrayPic = xyz.Clone();
        }
    }
}
```

And when I checked it, I realize that the value of `abc` == null and it leads to this exception. How can I solve this situation?

Comment: On what line does this error occur?

Comment: @Jerodev : it's already commented in the code

Comment: it's may be due to the size of `imgBox.Image`

Comment: Are you able to reproduce it reliably with some specific image that always triggers this exception ?

Comment: @Rahul Why does the size of imgBox.Image affect this situation?

Comment: I just edited my post and showed the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that the method

[Image.FromStream(stream)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x(v=vs.110).aspx)

throws an [ArgumentException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception(v=vs.110).aspx) on invalid picture data and null.